# Why my $window.localStorage object is empty?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have injected $window properly. But when I try to use `$window.localStorage`, the object `localStorage` is empty. What I am doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use localStorage.setItem , the example: [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If the local storage is empty, it doesn't mean its wrong or you are doing wrong. You can set items if required as follows:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```